# Ajax: Submit form with form name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a following form

```
<form autocomplete="off" id="settleUp" name="settleUp" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
             <div class="input-group">
                  <h4>Gautam Sawala</h4>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
               <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                          <i class="fa fa-eur"></i>
                    </span>
                    <input onChange="checkInput(this);" step="0.01" type="number" class="form-control" id="amount" name="amount" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" min="0.00" required>
                    <input id="payeeId" name="payeeId" value="3" hidden required>
               </div>
          </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
         <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Pay Back">
              </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to submit this form as ajax form submit,

```
$("#settleUp").submit(function(e){
        alert('here');
        $.ajax({
            type:"PUT",
            url: "/api/v1/settlements",
            data: $(this).serialize()+'&groupId='+'<?php echo $_GET['group_id'] ?>'+'&userId='+'<?php echo $_SESSION['userId'] ?>'+'&token='+'<?php echo $_SESSION['token'] ?>',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response){
                refreshExpenseListing();
                $('#settleUpModal').modal('hide');
                },
            error: function(data) {
                alert("failure");
              }
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

I am able to submit the form using the `id` of the form `$("#settleUp").submit(function(e)`

But I have multiple form as above and I want to submit the form using the `name` and not the `id`.

Is there a way in AJAX to do that?

Something like this,
`$("form[formname]").submit(function(e)`?

I have tried 
`$("form.settleUp").submit(function(e)` but this doesn't work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it using **[Attribute Equals Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)** :

```
$("form[name='settleUp']").submit(function(e){
    //Your code here
}
```

---

### Explanation

**First attempt :**

> ```
> $("form[formname]").submit(function(e)
> ```
>
> Your first attempt will not work since you give just the value `formname` without specifying the concerned attribute.

**Second attempt :**

> ```
> $("form[formname]").submit(function(e)
> ```
>
> It will not work it your form has a class name equal `settleUp` since `.` is a class selector.

---

To deal with forms added dynamically to the document by ajax you must use event delegation **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** :

```
$('body').on('submit', "form[name='settleUp']", function(e)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works for the existing form, but when I add the second form with the same name the ajax submit doesn't work on that form!

Comment: You're  welcome, it should work check the following example https://jsfiddle.net/uy7693mo/1/.

Comment: Yes, it works (I was wrong in first comment) when I have pre-written forms on the page, but when I append a new form through another AJAX, it doesn't work!